# Use whereHas and query pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

I have 3 table: `tasks`, `users`, `group`, and a pivot table `group_user`.

A task has `user_id`, `group_id`

A group_user pivot table has `user_id`, `group_id`

I want to query the tasks if the task belongs to a group of the user.

I don't want tasks from groups that the user doesn't belong to.

What I have so far:

```
public function index()
    {
        $userId = Auth::user()->id;

        return TaskResource::collection(
            Task::
                latest()
                ->whereHas('group', function($query) use($userId) {
                    $query->where('group_id', '=', $userId); // = is wrong 
                })
                ->get()
        );
    }
```

This gives me empty results, I tried to think about it but my head hurts

Comment: Should group_id equal to userId?!! Please show us the columns of each table to give a better answer.

Comment: @baleghsefat No it shouldn't, I'm following convention here when creating tables, I edited the question and added what inside the group_user table, it shouldn't be equal but I'm not sure what to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the tasks that are related to the group (or groups) of a user.

I supposed the relation name between the user table and the group table is 'users', in the Group model.

```
$userId = auth()->id();   

$tasks = Task::latest()
                   ->whereHas('group', function($query) use ($userId) {
                        $query->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($userId) {
                            $query->where('user_id', $userId);
                        });
                    })
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I want, and I can see what you did here, I learned something!

Answer (score 0):

Ive not tested this but i imagine you could nest the where has and use something like this in your whereHas block:

```
$query->whereHas('user', function($q2) use ($userId) {
    $q2->where('user_id', $userId);
});
```

Comment: This checks if the user is author of the task, but what i need is if the user belongs to the team this task belongs to.